# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: sapo] class or package not found

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I know there are other questions about this topic in StackOverflow, I read them but I can't get rid off this error.

I'm deploying my web app in JBoss-as-7.1.1 Final. It's a Maven proyect.

When I go to sapo-ear, rigth click, run as, maven install, it says "build succesfull". Then I try to full publish it in JBoss and then it says:

```
23:59:26,009 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."SAPo-ear.ear/SAPo-ejb.jar#sapo": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SAPo-ear.ear/SAPo-ejb.jar#sapo": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: sapo] class or package not found
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1400)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1183)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1047)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:692)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uy.edu.fing.tsi2.sapo.entities.Administrador from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @beaed3 (roots: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1317)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1389)
... 11 more
```

As far as I know, this could be caused by an inconsistence between persistence.xml and Adminstrador class.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="sapo">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/sapo</jta-data-source>
    <class>sapo.entities.Administrador</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.Almacen</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.AtributoValor</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.Comentario</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.Estandar</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.Mensaje</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.Producto</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.RolEnAlmacen</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.CatCompleja</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.ProductoGenerico</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.TransaccionInterna</class>
    <class>sapo.entities.TransaccionExterna</class>


    <properties>
        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And this is my Administrador class

```
@Entity
public class Administrador extends Usuario {

public Administrador(){
}

public Administrador(String nick, String password, String nombre,
        String mail, String direccion, Date fechaNacimiento,
        String linkImagen) {
    super(nick, password, nombre, mail, direccion, fechaNacimiento, linkImagen);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


}
```

Usuario is an abstrac class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Usuario {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Long id;
    //attribs, Getters setters and other methods
}
```

The most strange is this line from jboss stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uy.edu.fing.tsi2.sapo.entities.Administrador
```

This directory was all changed to just sapo.entities.Administrador, the long path was from an old version. I deleted this old project and cloned it again from git, I also deleted all files from C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments but stack trace keep throwing this old path.

My team mates are using the same configuration, cloned from the same git repository without any problem while I'm stacked with this.

Comment: For sure you tried, but just in case, try mvn clean

Comment: Try to delete the directories `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data` and `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp`. Sometimes JBoss does not delete old unpacked deployments from these directories and uses them instead of the new version.

Comment: @IkerAguayo I can't see this option. I only have maven > update project http://puu.sh/kIHwe/e28f2db02c.png

Comment: @siom those directories only contained empty folders. I removed them anyway, but without result

Comment: @siom... Thumbs up!. I had a similar issue and what you advised actually resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it, it was a problem in maven project configuration in one of the pom.xml, we had some problems with group ids from artefact and parents.

I don't have the exact answer because my team mate was who solved it, I'll ask her and update this answer with more detail later.

Answer (score 0):

If you have entries in your xml file as well as annotation for the corresponding class then sometime it cause problems. Try to remove one of both either annotation or xml entry for the corresponding class and then run again. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I'm using only annotation